# ReactorNettyHttpTracing (deprecated) equivalent in Micrometer Tracing

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-3, reactor-netty, micrometer-tracing

What would be the equivalent of `ReactorNettyHttpTracing (deprecated)` in Spring Boot 3 with Micrometer + Brave?

```
@Bean
public ReactorNettyHttpTracing reactorNettyHttpTracing(HttpTracing httpTracing) {
    return ReactorNettyHttpTracing.create(httpTracing);
}

.......
return WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(reactorNettyHttpTracing(null).decorateHttpClient(httpClient)))
```

Comment: Netty `HttpClient’ supports Micrometer tracing https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_tracing_4 and this is what spring team suggested “Prefer using the standard {@link reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient} and
 * {@link reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer} integration with“

Comment: Thanks, looks like Spring Team is working on something like Spring Sleuth for Spring Boot 3 and WebFlux Reactive logging. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33372

Comment: Spring Stelth will be just auto configuration and the core of this project got moved to Micrometer Tracing project and the instrumentations will be moved to Micrometer and all respective projects (no longer all instrumentations will be done in a single repository).

Comment: Having used to Spring Sleuth across many applications in Spring Boot 2, now that the same kind not being available in Spring Boot 3 is a tremendous rework :(

Comment: Checkout my issue here https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/2850 there is also an example on my sample project here: https://github.com/grassehh/spring-boot-3-tracing-coroutine
It is still in progress but the point is to find a replacement of the deprecated `ReactorNettyHttpTracing` class in Spring Boot 3