# What is the equivalent of TraceWebFilter with Micrometer Tracing?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-3, micrometer-tracing

Similar to [ReactorNettyHttpTracing (deprecated) equivalent in Micrometer Tracing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75046362/reactornettyhttptracing-deprecated-equivalent-in-micrometer-tracing) I am looking for the equivalent of [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceWebFilter](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/latest/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/web/TraceWebFilter.html) with the Micrometer Tracing